# Symfony 1.4 using Propel 1.5 with multiple databases

Tags: symfony1, propel

I am creating a Symfony 1.4 project using Propel 1.5. I would like to know if this can support multiple databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the answer is yes: take a look at [this page](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/194)

Answer (score 1):

```
    #config/orgdb.schema.yml
    orgdb:
      _attributes: {package:lib.model.orgdb} # add this line
      organization:
      id:           ~
```

Comment: This is actually subtle, but exactly what I needed.  Thanks, Jarod